# Remove invalid imap mail messages from the Summary buffer in gnus

Tags: emacs, gnus

When accessing IMAP mail (with nnimap) in GNUS, the Summary buffer often lists messages or that are actually no longer present in the group.

Selecting any of these messages/articles results in an 'Article canceled or expired' error message.  Quiting and restarting gnus doesn't change this (or refreshing with C-u M-g).

I can remove these articles from the Summary list by quiting gnus, and removing the ~/News directory and .newsrc.eld file, and then restarting gnus.

Is there anyway of getting the same result without reverting to deleting the files and directories?

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "agent" feature. This caches things and requires its own tweaking (I haven't done it personally).
Go to the server buffer (type "^" in the group buffer) go over your imap server line and type J r to remove the agent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try upgrading your version of Gnus. I used to have this problem a lot (along with every other user, it seems) and Lars did a massive rewrite of the IMAP code sometime this spring which seems to have fixed the problem here.